# Error when add application to App Store by Application Loader (App Write By Python)

Tags: python

I have built an app by python3 and using py2app to build the run packed then i use  product build to make file .pkg, but when i submit it to app store i have this error :

*ERROR ITMS-90060: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString '3.4.3, (c) 2001-2015 Python Software Foundation.' in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers."*

here is code in file info.plist

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>WebimgDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>WebimgDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.drakele.webimgdl</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>WebimgDL</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>@ Drake Le 2015</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>PyMainFileNames</key>
    <array>
        <string>__boot__</string>
    </array>
    <key>PyOptions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>alias</key>
        <false/>
        <key>argv_emulation</key>
        <false/>
        <key>emulate_shell_environment</key>
        <false/>
        <key>no_chdir</key>
        <false/>
        <key>prefer_ppc</key>
        <false/>
        <key>site_packages</key>
        <true/>
        <key>use_faulthandler</key>
        <false/>
        <key>use_pythonpath</key>
        <false/>
        <key>verbose</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>PyResourcePackages</key>
    <array/>
    <key>PyRuntimeLocations</key>
    <array>
        <string>@executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python</string>
    </array>
    <key>PythonInfoDict</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PythonExecutable</key>
        <string>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3</string>
        <key>PythonLongVersion</key>
        <string>3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]</string>
        <key>PythonShortVersion</key>
        <string>3.4</string>
        <key>py2app</key>
        <dict>
            <key>alias</key>
            <false/>
            <key>template</key>
            <string>app</string>
            <key>version</key>
            <string>0.9</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: the error is due to the string not being as per this file: "The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString  **'3.4.3, (c) 2001-2015 Python Software Foundation.' "** I suspect your build process is replacing the string or the whole file

Comment: i using common productbuild --content  myapp.app muapp.pkg to build pkg file, have you know any way to check file info.plist in .pkg file ?

Comment: Not having used the package creator I am not sure I would search the logs build and target folders for the outputs.